# Ways to salvage a tomato plant in winter

Tags: tomatoes, disposal

I received a tomato plant from work. It never blossomed, never produced fruit, but it grew to a fair height. My wife has ordered me to take it out of the house because it's attracting insects of some sort. Given it's October, I don't have much hope of it surviving the winter. I doubt it's even got seeds anywhere in it such that it might regrow in the Spring, but I figure I'd ask. Is there anything I can do with it short of simply planting it and forgetting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick it on the compost heap - it hasn't fruited, so there's no question of seeds, they're inside the fruits. I'm a bit curious as to why you kept in the house and didn't put it outside during the summer months, where it would have been much more likely to fruit though - they're not meant to be houseplants, though they can be grown in greenhouses. They are perennial plants in sub tropical regions, but anywhere the temperature drops below around 10 degrees C, they die in winter, and they're usually grown as annuals.

Comment: I had it out on the porch for a while, but it's covered, so it didn't get as much sun as I'd like. I don't really have places to put outside plants at the moment. Eventually, we'd like to fence in a garden, but currently, anything outside gets consumed by the deer in rapid order.

Comment: Oh I see - not worth growing tomatoes then unless you get a greenhouse!

Comment: Heh. And the deer are fast. I went ahead and stuck it in a patch of earth, just to give it a fighting chance, then went shopping. I came back and it's cropped to the ground.

Comment: Oh dear - bet your wife's pleased though!